# URL scheme Android Dialog (Intent Dialog) for Share from Web (url scheme)

Tags: android, dialog, share, url-scheme

Is there a URL scheme to open the Android Share Dialog for sharing text to applications that support Android Share Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it needs native Apps to support the ability to be opened from the Web.

I documented it here: https://paul.kinlan.me/sharing-natively-on-android-from-the-web/

You need to use the `intent:` syntax, have an action of SEND, set the type to be text/plain. Set the Extra Text and Extra Subject.  You can also specify a fallback URL that the browser will open if there are no Apps available on the system.

A complete example is below:

```
intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.SEND;type=text/plain;S.android.intent.extra.TEXT=https%3A%2F%2Fpaul.kinlan.me%2F;S.android.intent.extra.SUBJECT=Amazing;S.browser_fallback_url=https:%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fintent%2Ftweet;end
```